# How can I define a Neo4j node property from 2 possible paths with a cypher query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Quite new to neo4j/cypher. Im trying to return a property that is accessed by 2 different paths, depending on the Label, in this case, the Label of (n).

```
MATCH (k:KeyNode)<-[:BASED_ON]-(n)-[:CONTROLS|:MODIFIES]->()
    WHERE id(k)=123456
    //if label(n) = LabelA
    OPTIONAL MATCH (n)<-[:LABEL_A_REL]-(c:Controller)-[:CONTROLS]->(r:Resource)-[:TYPE_OF]->(rt:ResourceType) 
    //if label(n) = NotLabelA
    OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[:LABEL_NOT_A_REL]->(r:Resource)-[:TYPE_OF]->(rt:ResourceType) 
    OPTIONAL MATCH (r)-[:PARENT*]->(ro:Room) 
    RETURN ID(r) as resourceId, ID(ro) as siteId, ID(rt) as rt:ResourceType
```

As is, the path defined 1st optional match and its defined nodes take precedence, leaving the 2nd opt match/path node redefinitions untouched, i assume because cypher won't redefine a variable. The goal is to get (r) and (rt) found on 2 possible paths.

I considered using CASE WHEN structure, but from the documentation I see only the option to return single properties, and not multiple (though i could be wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be an approach:

```
MATCH (k:KeyNode)<-[:BASED_ON]-(n)-[:CONTROLS|:MODIFIES]->()
    WHERE id(k)=123456
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)<-[:LABEL_A_REL]-(c:Controller)-[:CONTROLS]->(r1:Resource)-[:TYPE_OF]->(rt1:ResourceType)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[:LABEL_NOT_A_REL]->(r2:Resource)-[:TYPE_OF]->(rt2:ResourceType)

// COALESCE to deal with precedence
WITH COALESCE(r1,r2) AS r,
     COALESCE(rt1,rt2) AS rt

OPTIONAL MATCH (r)-[:PARENT*]->(ro:Room)
RETURN ID(r) as resourceId, ID(ro) as siteId, ID(rt) as rt:ResourceType
```